# Clarification on .innerHTML and .html vulnerability to malicious injection

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that taking a value from an untrusted source like a form input or a query string etc and using it with .innerHTML or .html is a security risk.

But is there any risk in printing HTML from a variable like this:

```
var html = 'Check out this <a href="/link-here/">link</a>';
$("#link-div").html(html);

<div id="link-div"></div>
```

Like, as long as the html comes from your own code and no external source then is there anything to look out for?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to prevent.  JavaScript is client side, so the user can manipulate it.  But that wouldn't be a concern if you aren't posting the data.  If you're posting the data, you should do server side validation.

Comment: The risk is when the HTML comes from an untrusted source. For instance, if you're displaying an email, you can't trust the email sender.

Comment: But if you're generating the HTML entirely yourself, without including any untrusted data, you should be safe.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [security.se], but I'd check their [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely no risk doing this, you just chose to render a link with code. As your code is not based on user input (text fields, URL, HTTP headers, ...) it won't behave in an unwanted way and endanger your users.

Comment: +1 The only way it can become a vulnerability, is if O.P decides to use dynamic value for "link-here" (typically based on user input) in html variable